# Jquery multiple select dropdown getting script running error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using multiple select dropdown box with jquery plugin(http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Vn3Q3xQR). I have around 5000 records(fetched from db) to be populated in this dropdown box. I am getting records from db properly but while populating in this dropdown box, getting script running error.

I am using IE8, JQuery-1.5.1 and Jquery-UI 1.8.13.

Please find my code below:
In Jquery :

```
$('#testStn').multipleSelect({
    width: '40%'
});
```

and populating the records in select box as below:

```
<select name="testStn" id="testStn" multiple="multiple"/>
    <option value="*" selected>ALL</option>
    <%
        for (String stn : hubList) {
        %>
        <option value="<%= stn %>"><%= stn %></option>                          
        <%  
    }
    %>                            
    <option>---</option>
    <% 
    if(stnList != null && stnList.size() > 0 )
    {
        for ( String stn : stnList) {
            %>
            <option value="<%=stn %>"><%=stn%></option>
            <%
        }
    }
    %>
</select>
```

Any help to get rid of this script running error and for loading these records in quick time to multiselect dropdown would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I have also tried with below plugins but getting same script running error. **[Plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)**

Comment: we need to see how you have implemented your code?? ajax?? how you are fetching it from db and assigning it to select?? Post some piece of code!

Comment: Please edit your question with whatever you have posted in comments!! and delete your comments

Comment: + post the rendered HTML of your select list if possible to understand more about the problem!